# How to constrain the width of GridView with a Scrollbar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-gridview, flutter-scrollbar

I am trying to display a scrollbar on the right-hand side of a ScrollView (a GridView in this case) but constraining the width of the scrollable area while still displaying a scrollbar on the right-hand side. I can't see how to customize the position of the scrollbar relative to the Scrollable

See [this DartPad for an example](https://dartpad.dev/3eff738ec521977e5c54d5ab719a85bf).

In the example above, the ScrollBar is displayed directly to the right hand side of the GridView's children, but I would prefer to have it all the way to the right. I can't find any affordances in the GridView constructor to help me with this. Does this require a CustomScrollView or can this be achieved with a normal GridView?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to swap the Center and Scrollbar widgets.

Before:

```
Center
  Scrollbar
    ConstrainedBox
```

After:

```
Scrollbar
  Center
    ConstrainedBox
```

https://dartpad.dev/09ddf64d254b0c331920cf970acc4447

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary that this GridView to have exactly 400px in width? If this is not necessary you can set the width of your ConstrainedBox like:

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Then the GridView will have the exact size as your screen, so in consequence th scroll bar will be where you want it to be.